# Use swift class returned by an objective c class in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a cocoa pod library with a legacy objective c service that is partially refactored into swift. The objective c service uses and returns some swift classes.

The cocoa pod library is used in a project with both objective c and swift.

When the service is used from swift code, the returned class types are no longer recognized as its original types, but rather as '__ObjC.' class types.

Any idea what should be done or how to tackle this problem?

Simplified code below:

------ cocoa pod library ------

The swift classes

```
@objc public class PlayableItem: NSObject{
    @objc public var id: Int {
        get {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    @objc public var title: String {
        get {
            return "";
        }
    }
}

@objc public class ApiTrack : PlayableItem {
    private var _id: Int
    @objc override public var id: Int {
        get {
            return self._id
        }
        set{
            self._id = newValue
        }
    }
    private var _title: String
    @objc override public var title: String {
        get {
            return self._title
        }
        set{
            self._title = newValue
        }
    }
}

@objc public class ApiMessage: ApiTrack {
    //extra properties etc
}

@objc public class ApiSong: ApiTrack {
    //extra properties etc
}
```

The objective c legacy service (simplified test version)

TestProxy.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <TunifyApi/TunifyApi-Swift.h>

@interface TestProxy : NSObject

+ (TestProxy *) sharedProxy;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) PlayableItem *firstPlayableItem;

@end
```

TestProxy.m file

```
#import "TestProxy.h"

static TestProxy *shared = nil;

@implementation TestProxy

+ (TestProxy *) sharedProxy{
    @synchronized(shared){
        if (!shared || shared == nil){
            shared = [[TestProxy alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return shared;
}

- (PlayableItem *) firstPlayableItem{
    //Returns a playable item that can be a ApiMessage or ApiSong
}

@end
```

I also have a general header file ('TunifyApi.h') that imports all the objective c headers that we need to use:

```
#import "TestProxy.h"
```

------ files from project ------

The bridging header imports the general header file of the pod:

```
#import "TunifyApi/TunifyApi.h"
```

Inside a swift file, when trying to use the TestProxy service:

```
private func testFirstTrack(){
    //this works, but no properties can be accesssed
    var firstPlayableItem1 = TestProxy.shared().firstPlayableItem

    //this results in an compile error
    var firstPlayableItem2 : PlayableItem? = TestProxy.shared().firstPlayableItem
}
```

The compile error:
Cannot convert value of type '__ObjC.PlayableItem?' to specified type 'TunifyApi.PlayableItem?'

When using the code from objective c, everything looks good:

```
- (void) testFirstTrack{
    
    PlayableItem *firstPlayableItem = [TestProxy sharedProxy].firstPlayableItem;
    //All properties can be accessed, downcasting is available etc
    if (firstPlayableItem && [firstPlayableItem isKindOfClass:[ApiTrack class]]){
        ApiTrack *firstTrack = (ApiTrack *) firstPlayableItem;
    }

}
```

Comment: The fact that this is a "cocoa pod library" is probably germane here, but also makes it nearly impossible to test. Is there any chance you could convert to SPM?

Comment: The legacy code uses some c++ files bridged with mm files, is that possible with SPM?
We also support iOS9, but i suppose that will not be a problem
We use 16 pods, so i'll have to change them all to SPM in order to only use 1 package manager.

Comment: I have nooooooo idea how C++ plays into this. What we do on our project is switch to SPM for whatever has an SPM option. So at this point we are half pods and half packages, roughly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error was because I used the swift bridging file of the library in some of the header files of the project.

After moving the imports to the .m files everything worked as expected. So this needs to be in the .m files:

```
#import <TunifyApi/TunifyApi-Swift.h>
```

If the classes are needed in any objective-c header file, the correct way to use them is to forward declare them like this:

```
@class PlayableItem;
```